# check file type in dropzone

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, dropzone.js

I have following code to upload excel sheet using dropzone.js with certain condition such as maximum number of file is 1 and only excel type is accepted...
when multiple file is uploaded with correct file type then the error is initiated first and message is generated by `alert('please enter correct file format')` and then only the real error message is alerted by `alert('You cannot upload more then 1 file at a time.')` . so, my question is how to show real error message when error is initialized...

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myAwesomeDropzone", {
  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>test/upload_excel_file",
  maxFiles: 1,
  acceptedFiles: ".xls,.xlsx",
  dictDefaultMessage:
    "Drag an excel sheet here to upload, or click to select one",
  init: function () {
    this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function (file) {
      alert("You cannot upload more then 1 file at a time.");
      this.removeFile(file);
    });

    this.on("error", function (file) {
      var type = file.type;
      //alert(type);
      if (type != "application/vnd.ms-excel") {
        alert("please enter correct file format");
        this.removeFile(file);
      } else if (
        type !=
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
      ) {
        alert("please enter correct file format");
        this.removeFile(file);
      }
    });
  },
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The incorrect file type message happens because you with your if statements you will obviously fall into one of the 2 conditions giving the error.

So instead you should use:

```
switch(file.type)
{
    case 'application/vnd.ms-excel':
    case 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet':
    break;
    default:
    alert('please enter correct file format');
    break;
}
```

Comment: I don't suppose you experienced any issues with IE11 at all? I'm currently faced with an issue where type is just an empty string, but I have no issues like this in other browsers. Struggling to find anything online regarding this as well. Thanks!

Comment: I've just found something on their Github actually just for future reference should anyone need it https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/1143